# What happens to running applications of .net 3.0 while upgrade happens to .net 4.0?

Tags: .net

Will upgrade of .net framework from 3 to 4 will shut down all the applications running in .net 3.0.? I had the server in which we have hosted some applications in IIS. But what i have seen is due to upgrade of framework all applications were stopped. Was that correct?

Comment: They use different versions of the CLR, so I don't see any reason why existing applications would be stopped. Have you tried it? Do you mean they were stopped by the system, or as part of your own procedures?

Comment: Not only IIS hosted apps , but also some windows applications were stopped while upgradation. I dont know the exact reason. We are still investigating and i can see from eventlog that system is rebooted after upgrade. Thats why previously running applications were stopped.

Answer (score 3):

You can run .NET 3.0 and 4.0 applications side-by-side.

However, as you bring .NET 4.0 applications online, you will need to configure the website to use 4.0 and also set any apps running 4.0 to run in a different Application Pool.  (This *may* be why the old ones were stopped.)

There are instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7) and [here](http://www.visualwebgui.com/Developers/KB/tabid/654/article/deploying_net40_applications/Default.aspx) for doing that if you need them.

Comment: But when some applications are already running in 3.0 and simultaneously 4.0 upgrade happens. Thne what will happen?

Comment: It depends on if someone visits a page in a .NET 2.0 - 3.5  website and a .NET4.0 website while they are running in the same application pool.  If that happens, all applications will crash and you'll get event log entries explaining why.